# Get data of user after login (but not with craft()->userSession->getUser())

Tags: php, craft-pro

Can I directly get the data of the user that I just logged in with `craft()->userSession->login($username, $password)` ? (not from a method that uses the SESSION like `craft()->userSession->getUser()` though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the any identifying information about the user (user ID, email, username, UID), you can use one of the UsersService's methods:

[`craft()->users->getUserById()`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/UsersService#getUserById-detail)

[`craft()->users->getUserByUsernameOrEmail()`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/UsersService#getUserByUsernameOrEmail-detail)

[`craft()->users->getUserByUid()`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/UsersService#getUserByUid-detail)

[`craft()->users->getUserByEmail()`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/UsersService#getUserByEmail-detail)

They will each return a [UserModel](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/UserModel) object to interact with.